# Compare the result from decode

Tags: sql, oracle

How to compare the result that I got from decode function with another value. Here is the query.

```
select  employee,
SUM(DECODE(type, 'credit' , amount,
                  'debit', allAmount)) result, 
sign(result > 1000)
from table group by employee;
```

The result I am getting using this `SUM(DECODE(type, 'credit' , amount, 'debit', allAmount))` result, has to be compared with some value called '1000'. How to compare?

Comment: Compare where? Do you only want rows where that decoded value is more than 1000? (Or the absolute of that is more than 1000, perhaps). What is the sign line intended to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with x as 
(select  employee,
SUM(DECODE(type, 'credit' , amount,
                 'debit', allAmount)) result
from table group by employee)
select * from x where result > 1000
```

Assuming you need rows which match you `result > 1000` condition, this will do the job.

Comment: You do not need to use the with construction. This looks a bit intimidating for a novice. In this simple case a  simple inline view will do.

Comment: with x as 
(select  employee,
SUM(DECODE(type, 'credit' , amount,
                 'debit', allAmount)) result
from table group by employee)
select * from x where result > 1000 ; This is working.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method:

```
select employee
     , sum(decode(type, 'credit', amount
                      , 'debit', allAmmount)) result
  from table
 group by employee
having sum(decode(type, 'credit', amount
                      , 'debit', allAmmount)) > 1000;
```